# Building tensorflow from source with Docker

Tags: python, git, docker, tensorflow

Sorry for this basic question, bit of a Docker noob here.

I'm trying to [build tensorflow from source](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source) following the Docker instructions:

> docker pull tensorflow/tensorflow:devel
>
> docker run -it -w /tensorflow -v $PWD:/mnt -e HOST_PERMS="$(id -u):$(id -g)" \
>       tensorflow/tensorflow:devel bash
>
> git pull  # within the container, download the latest source code

Here are the commands I run in the terminal (on Ubuntu), along with their output:

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 19.03.2, build 6a30dfc

$ docker pull tensorflow/tensorflow:devel
devel: Pulling from tensorflow/tensorflow
Digest: sha256:0ee065743f0001f922561bcba914013929a88263ec2a5af21ba35899c3ac85a7
Status: Image is up to date for tensorflow/tensorflow:devel
docker.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:devel

$ docker run -it -w /tensorflow -v $PWD:/mnt -e HOST_PERMS="$(id -u):$(id -g)" \
>     tensorflow/tensorflow:devel bash

________                               _______________                
___  __/__________________________________  ____/__  /________      __
__  /  _  _ \_  __ \_  ___/  __ \_  ___/_  /_   __  /_  __ \_ | /| / /
_  /   /  __/  / / /(__  )/ /_/ /  /   _  __/   _  / / /_/ /_ |/ |/ / 
/_/    \___//_/ /_//____/ \____//_/    /_/      /_/  \____/____/|__/


WARNING: You are running this container as root, which can cause new files in
mounted volumes to be created as the root user on your host machine.

To avoid this, run the container by specifying your user's userid:

$ docker run -u $(id -u):$(id -g) args...

root@4746a002f18e:/tensorflow#
```

But now, if I run `git pull` as instructed, I get

```
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

How should I instead be running these commands?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the doc your referenced is not aligned with the current layout of the image. The correct folder where tensorflow sources are installed is `/tensorflow_src`.

Just change the option in your `docker run` command line => `-w /tensorflow_src` (or `cd /tensorflow_src` once in the container), and you should immediately be able to pull.

Tests on my side:

```
$ docker run -it --rm -w /tensorflow_src -v $PWD:/mnt -e HOST_PERMS="$(id -u):$(id -g)" tensorflow/tensorflow:devel bash

________                               _______________                
___  __/__________________________________  ____/__  /________      __
__  /  _  _ \_  __ \_  ___/  __ \_  ___/_  /_   __  /_  __ \_ | /| / /
_  /   /  __/  / / /(__  )/ /_/ /  /   _  __/   _  / / /_/ /_ |/ |/ / 
/_/    \___//_/ /_//____/ \____//_/    /_/      /_/  \____/____/|__/


WARNING: You are running this container as root, which can cause new files in
mounted volumes to be created as the root user on your host machine.

To avoid this, run the container by specifying your user's userid:

$ docker run -u $(id -u):$(id -g) args...

root@2f5660528e98:/tensorflow_src# git pull
remote: Enumerating objects: 7328, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (7328/7328), done.
remote: Total 12261 (delta 7328), reused 7328 (delta 7328), pack-reused 4933
Receiving objects: 100% (12261/12261), 8.59 MiB | 8.19 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (10031/10031), completed with 2861 local objects.
```